# Looking for OP-Amp with good rail to rail performance, 5V to 0V

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, amplifier, analog, dsp

There are thousands of OP-Amps on Farnell's website, so I thought asking the stack-exchange community might be a good idea. I am looking for an OP-Amp for use in my project.

I currently have an OP-Amp, but it hasn't quite performed as well as I had hoped. The problem I have is that it won't drive its output lower than about 0.8 V and won't drive higher than 4.2 V. I am running this device from 0 V and 5 V rails.

The reason for the choice of power supply is to prevent signals outside of this range from damaging an ADC I am using. The ADC's analog input must remain within the 0 V to 5 V range.

I am processing audio signals, so other desirable things include slew rates of ~0.4 V/us or greater, bandwidth of 20 kHz or greater, and ideally in the standard pin arrangement for DIP 8 packages. (I call it a standard arrangement: VCC is pin 5, ground is pin 4, the output 1 is pin 1, v-1 is pin 2, v+1 is pin 3, output 2 is pin 6, v-2 is pin 7 and v+2 is pin 8.)

Is there anyone who knows of a device they could suggest? Any other advice would be welcome.

Edit: I should mention that I have found the device MCP6002, which I think would be an improvement, does this look like the sort of thing I might want to use?

Comment: What amplifier were you using? The swing you mention means you're losing about half a bit from the ADC, not disastrous unless you're right on the edge.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am using a 10 bit ADC, which although I have heard lots of people tell me that 10 bits is loads and that I will start running into problems with noise, this just isn't true. 10 bits is not loads considering most digital audio devices produce 16 bit output. For this reason, I need to use every voltage step available to me. It would have been better to have used a 12 or 14 bit adc and used a smaller voltage range, but I couldn't get one with parallel output. I had to have parallel output for speed, as it is interfacing to a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I had to use a Raspberry Pi because I wanted OpenGL output as well as GPIO. I was using this amplifier: TLE2072 - I chose that originally because of it's high slew rate and low distortion / high quality performance. I didn't consider at the time what the rail-to-rail performance was like.

Answer (score 2):

Best in class input/output rail-to-rail op. amps.:

- OPA350 (includes DIP-8)
- OPA333 (Non DIP).

Also, a lot of other great features. See the datasheets.

Comment: It's best to stay away from r-r input unless you really need it, IMHO.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany For what reason? I would imagine that rail to rail input is useful if I want to be able to process signals in a voltage range as wide as possible (of course only if the op amp is not used as an amplifier).

Comment: @maxkl It increases cost (which is often, but not always, very important in real designs) and frequently involves technical trade-offs. For example, for many parts  there's a shift in Vos as the common-mode input voltage changes within  the range.

Answer (score 0):

Digikey has the best search engine.  Lots of useful parameters to search over.